# IntelliJ, unable to share Project on GitHub (Permission Denied)

Tags: github, intellij-idea, repository, gitlab, permission-denied

I'm new to Git and GitHub/GitLab. I try to share my project to GitHub but it throws this exception:

```
Can't finish GitHub sharing process
        Successfully created project 'LiveGame1' on GitHub, but initial push failed:
        git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
        Could not read from remote repository.
        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

I'm also able to clone a repository via internet link, but not via "git@github.com:/username/repository_name".

How can I fix this error and am I able to share my project directly to GitLab?

Comment: Is this repository **yours**?

Comment: I am able to clone every public repository, but I try to share a project of mine, but it throws this exception

Comment: I just want to know, is the user shown in `git remote` url of your current repository (which may be a HTTPS way `https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git`, or SCP way `git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git`), yourself or your organization, or someone other?

Comment: Yes, its my repo and my username

Comment: To add new project to github, while creating new repository on github, leave **Initialize this repository with a README** unselected. This might be the solution because I've faced the same problem once.

Answer (score 10):

This article helped me get things squared away on my Windows 10 box:

https://richardballard.co.uk/ssh-keys-on-windows-10/

**Note**:  The first section in the article should be titled "Enable the SSH **Client** in Windows" and should refer to getting the SSH **Client** enabled, not the server.

If you can get `ssh -T git@github.com` working without prompting you for your password, as described in the above article, then you'll be able to push from IntelliJ just fine.

The keys were to:

- get the **OpenSSH Authentication Agent service** running in Windows
- make sure `ssh-add` that is invoked is the one provided in `C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH`
- make sure git is also configured to use the ssh provided by Windows:

`git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"`

When generating your keys with `ssh-keygen` consider using the ecdsa algorithm as described here:  https://www.ssh.com/ssh/keygen/

Also important was cleaning up anything else that was trying to do ssh outside of windows (like Putty).  One problem I kept facing with 'invalid format' when trying to run `ssh-add` I believe was caused by a different `ssh-add` program on my path that was being used rather than the one from OpenSSH that ships with Windows.

Comment: For me adding config to ssh_config worked. Also I had to unset this otherwise it throws error `git config --global core.sshCommand "'C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe'"`.

Answer (score 7):

There are loads of suggestions here
[How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)
and here
[Git gives me a “Permission Denied” error when writing files that I am pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200556/git-gives-me-a-permission-denied-error-when-writing-files-that-i-am-pulling)
depending on the OS.

For me on Windows in IntelliJ the solution has been the one which is mentioned here:
[Can't access git using SSH keys](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004124959-IntelliJ-2019-1-3-Can-t-access-git-using-SSH-keys).

I edited the **ssh_config**-File within the git-Installation, which IntelliJ uses with the Host of the sources and all worked.

File e.g.:

> C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config

Change within the file e.g.:

```
Host bitbucket.org
    IdentityFile C:\Users\User\.ssh\id_ssh
```

Edit: As mentioned in a comment (for Linux), it is also possible on Windows, to add a config file in your lokal user home directory: `C:\Users\<USER>\.ssh\config` with the mentioned hostname(s) from above. This may be the better solution, if you are using multiple git-Installations or don't have access (due to missing admin-permissions) to your git-Installation.

Comment: For me on Linux it was the same. Add to ~/.ssh/config:
```Host github.com
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_public_key.pub
```
Fun fact is that in normal terminal I didn't have to do it. I had to do it for Intellij terminal to communicate with Github repository.

Answer (score 4):

I have faced same problem and i generated public key for intelliJ in github account.

**Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access token**

Then generate a new token for intelliJ by providing necessary **scope and description.and copy the token key**.

After that in intelliJ **select Login via token access**.Login by pasting the key in the form displayed.

Thank you

Comment: Idea doesn't have Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access token chapter

Comment: Settings -> Developer settings -> Personal access token is on github on top right place next your profile pic

Answer (score 4):

I'm using **Windows 10** and **PuTTY authentication agent** (with password protected SSH key) and this worked for me - for my Bitbucket and Github accounts where I uploaded my SSH key.

> **Steps to integrate 'SSH' key in Intellij -**
>
> 1. Open 'PuTTYgen' application.
> 2. Click on 'File > Load private key'.
> 3. Choose your .ppk file from directory.
> 4. Click on 'Conversions > Export OpenSSH key'.
> 5. Save the file in 'C:\Users\(your username)\.ssh' folder with 'id_rsa' name.
> 6. Open Intellij.
> 7. Click on 'File > Settings'.
> 8. Expand 'Version Control'.
> 9. Expand 'Subversion'.
> 10. Click on 'SSH'.
> 11. Select 'Private key' radio button.
> 12. Select the generated file stored in 'C:\Users\(your username)\.ssh' folder.
> 13. Click on 'Ok' button.
>
> Test configuration: Click 'VCS > Git > Fetch'. If 'Fetch Successful'
> message displays, your configuration is successful

Source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000011270-How-to-set-up-git-SSH-keys-?page=1#community_comment_360001445600

Answer (score 1):

This question is too broad. Needs more details to clarify.

Run `git remote show -n origin` (Assuming you are on branch `origin`. `-n` flag means "do not query remotes", which reduce the operating time for web requests.), you may see the remote URL.

In many common cases, for example on GitHub, [Git URLs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_git_urls_a_id_urls_a) are in HTTPS protocols

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>.git
```

or SSH protocols

```
git@github.com:<user>/<repo>.git
```

If the field `user` is not you, or one of your organizations, then you seems trying to contribute to someone's repository. Please [fork](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/) and [create a pull request](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-from-a-fork/) to do so. You may need to change your local repo's remote url with command

```
git remote set-url <branch> <newurl>
```

If `user` is you, then check if you have input your token correctly.

- If you are using HTTPS protocol, check the username and password you input. You may need to check [Git Credentials](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials).
- If you are using SSH protocol, make sure you have the corresponding SSH key from your computer to [GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/). You may test the connection with command `ssh -T git@github.com`.

**Update 1:** There seems a typo in your question, `git@github.com:/username/repository_name`. Note the first slash. I am not sure if it troubles.

**Update 2:** Check your Git credentials **save in your IntelliJ IDEA** in `File -> Settings -> Version Control -> GitHub`

**Update 3:** You are able to share it to GitLab too, just add one remote, for example run command `git remote add gitlab <url>`.

Comment: How can I type "git remote show -n origin" in IntelliJ?

Comment: @Lockna There is a `Terminal` in the bottom of main window. Use top menu bar `VCS -> Git -> Remotes...` is also OK.

Answer (score 1):

I have had a similar issue where I could not pull changes with SSH git, and solved the issue by adding SSH Configuration in Intellij.

Steps:

- Go to Preferences
- Tools
- Select "SSH Configurations"
- Then add a new configuration as shown in the screenshot below:
  [image]

I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I can share a similar situation & answer regarding WebStorm.

I had previously stored a password for a different `SSH` key, I added a new key (don't forget `ssh-agent -s` if on e.g. Mac) but WebStorm didn't pick up on it.

No context is given within WebStorm for the upcoming error message, it's sadly the generic one from `git`:

```
Push failed

<project>: git@<domain>: Permission denied (publickey).

Could not read from remote repository.
                    
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

As mentioned and linked in [several](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004124959-IntelliJ-2019-1-3-Can-t-access-git-using-SSH-keys), [several](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000114504--Solved-Git-SHH-Private-Key-PAssPhrase) [issues](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210181) on JetBrains' IntelliJ tracker and/or forums (they led me here), WebStorm (and I assume IntelliJ as well) *uses your SSH config dotfile* under the hood. This implies using the native `ssh` client (in previous versions, `Settings » Version Control » git » SSH Executable to "native"`) or using a Configuration (`Settings » Tools » SSH Configuration`s)

Thus, creating or editing your `SSH` `config` (e.g. Mac: `~/.ssh/config`) to include e.g.

```
Host <domain>
    User git
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/<your private SSH key file, usually `id_...`>
```

will then make WebStorm pick up upon the `git` `remote`'s `domain` and prompt you for your password for the configured SSH key/SSH config item.

(Remember to replace placeholders marked with `<placeholder>` above).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub command, copied the result and in Github/settings/ssh and gpg keys added "new ssh key" and pasted the result there and save
then run again "git push -u origin main" and it worked.