# Git error could not open log file for tracing: Permission denied

Tags: git

I am running `git version` command from Git Bash and it is giving me error as follows.
What is wrong?

I have reinstalled git again -

```
$ git version
warning: could not open 'C:\Users\sgupt503git.log' for tracing: Permission denied
git version 2.17.1.windows.2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git gives me a "Permission Denied" error when writing files that I am pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200556/git-gives-me-a-permission-denied-error-when-writing-files-that-i-am-pulling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like [GIT_TRACE](https://git-scm.com/docs/git#Documentation/git.txt-codeGITTRACEcode) (Edit: see PS) variable is enabled in your environment. The environment settings almost always[*] are stored so that they are not affected by git reinstallation.

It looks like the directory `C:\Users\` is not usually writable for users, that's why you are getting the error.

To fix the issue, open your environment variables settings and look up there for the variable `GIT_TRACE...` to remove it. If it's not there is can be in the shell start script like `~/.bashrc`. Check if the issue reproduces if you start the git from `cmd.exe`.

[*] there may be some files in `/etc` which may affect environment of the bash session and are usually removed at git for windows uninstallation. But it is very unlikely anybody has touched them.

PS: actually, there are many variables like "GIT_TRACE...", scroll down in the document for them.