# my git bash terminal keeps telling me: cannot create directory: Permission denied

Tags: git

I tried to make a new directory in my git bash with the command `mkdir` but it keeps telling me "cannot create directory, permission denied"

```
Dell E@DESKTOP-9KIQ MING/
$ mkdir git_new
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘git_new’: Permission denied
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git gives me a "Permission Denied" error when writing files that I am pulling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9200556/git-gives-me-a-permission-denied-error-when-writing-files-that-i-am-pulling)

Comment: Well, do you have permission to create folders where you're trying to do that?

Comment: i guess so, actually, I'm new to git, so i was supposed to follow a certain convention but for some reason ,it doesnt create the new directory, i have no idea why...

Comment: How do i know if i have permission please

Comment: Please type `pwd` to know exactly where you are when doing this, as well as `ls -la` to check all permissions in your local repository (including on itself). Also, please tell us what is your exact OS. Is it a genuine Linux/Unix or is it inside a Windows 10 ?

Comment: it is on a windows 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on Windows 10 in a git bash session, type at least "`cd`" (to go to your homedir) before any `mkdir`.

It looks like you are on '`/`' (root folder), which is not owned by you.